# Why is infinite field so important here? Clearing my fundamental concept in ring theory.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, integral-domain

This is a question on clearing one of my basic concepts rather than a problem. We know that if $F$ is a field then $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain and hence an Integral domain. Now in an integral domain say $F[x]$ if $f,g \in F[x]$ if $fg=0$ then either $f=0$ or $g=0$. **1) Now does this $f=0$ imply that $f$ is just the element zero $\in F$ or $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in F$ or something else that is going over my head right now.**

This is a basic conception problem that irritates me for some time so that I thought to ask you all. Because **2) in $\Bbb Z_2$ we have $x^2-x$ is zero polynomial but $x^2-x$ isn't the number zero $\in \Bbb Z_2$ but $x^2-x=0$ for all $x \in \Bbb Z_2$. Now $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ is an integral domain so $x^2-x=0 \Rightarrow x=0 $ or $x-1=0$ which is definitely not true $x \in \Bbb Z_2$.** I think I am seriously lacking a fundamental concept.

Let me know why this question bugs me a lot. I was trying to prove [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297832/suppose-g-has-the-property-that-if-fx%E2%89%A00-then-gx-0-then-prove-that) to prove [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179652/zariski-open-sets-are-dense)  by my own. Then I realized that we have to use Hilbert Nullstelensatz which is standard over an algebraically closed field and hence this is infinite.

But **3) what will happen with finite fields? Why is the infiniteness so important? Probably because of the example I gave in 2). But even in finite field $fg=0$ should imply $f=0$ or $g=0$ then [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3297832/suppose-g-has-the-property-that-if-fx%E2%89%A00-then-gx-0-then-prove-that) should be true over finite field that is why I lost my way in a circular arguement**.

I don't know whether I am making any sense or not! Probably you have got that I am utterly confused. I am sorry if I am saying something miserable. Please help

**Edit:**

I read those links still I am confused. Can anyone please answer this:

**$x^2-x=x(x-1)=0=f(x)g(x)$ where $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x-1$ As $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ is an integral domain we have $f(x)=x=0$ or $g(x)=x-1=0$ what does this mean $f(x)$ is the zero polynomial in  $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ or $g(x)$ is the zero polynomial in  $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ or what! By the way you can say that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both of them are not zero in $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ then where is the fallacy!! you can mark my question as duplicate,downvote but please help me here**

Comment: I read it but still could not understand that $x^2-x=x(x-1)=0=f(x)g(x)$ where $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=x-1$ As $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ is an integral domain we have $f(x)=x=0$ or $g(x)=x-1=0$ what does this mean $f(x)$ is the zero polynomial in  $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ or $g(x)$ is the zero polynomial in  $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ or what! By the way you can say that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both of them are not zero in $\Bbb Z_2[x]$ then where is the fallacy!!

Comment: In $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})[x]$, $x^2-x$ is *not* the zero polynomial. If $K$ is an infinite field, then $0$ is the only polynomial $p(x)\in K[x]$ with the property that $p(a) = 0_K$ for all $a\in K$ (why? because a $p(x)$ has at most $\text{deg}(p)$ roots). But if $K$ is a finite field, there are non-zero polynomials which evaluate to $0_K$ on every element of $K$, e.g. $\prod_{a\in K}(x-a)$.

Comment: Okay, what will happen with $K[x_1,x_2]$ or rather say $K[x_1,....,x_n]$, $K$ infinite, where $n \geq 2$. Here is $0$ the only polynomial $p(x_1,..,x_n)\in K[x_1,....,x_n]$ with  with the property that $p(a)=0_K$ for all $a∈K^n$. If so, why?

Comment: Induction on $n$. My previous comment settles the base case. Now view a non-zero polynomial $p\in K[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ as a polynomial in the single variable $x_n$ with coefficients in the ring $K[x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}]$. The leading term of this polynomial looks like $q(x_1,\dots,x_{n-1})x_n^d$ for some $d\geq 0$, where $q$ is a non-zero polynomial. By induction, there exist $a_1,\dots,a_{n-1}\in K$ such that $q(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1})\neq 0_K$. Then $p(a_1,\dots,a_{n-1},x_n)\in K[x_n]$ is a non-zero polynomial (it has degree $d$), so by the base case there is $a_n\in K$ s.t. $p(a_1,\dots,a_n)\neq 0$.

Comment: See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/23241/identically-zero-multivariate-polynomial-function

Comment: You asked the same question yesterday, why did you delete it. The addition multiplication of polynomials in $\Bbb{Z}_2[x]$ is defined only from their coefficients, it is not the same as the polynomials functions $\Bbb{Z}_2\to\Bbb{Z}_2$

Comment: @reuns Are you telling me? Neither I asked the same question yesterday and nor I deleted it. I have possibly edited it. If I am getting downvotes because of this please give me upvotes.

Comment: It is because I wrote the exact same comment yesterday to someone having the same problem as you with polynomials with coefficients in finite fields. Then the ring $k[x]$ is defined abstractly just in term of the coefficients and the operations of $k$, nowhere it is mentionning that we can evaluate $f$ at $f(a),a\in k$

Comment: Definitely, not me. You can check my activity.