# Are $ \mathbb{A}^n (k ) = k^n $ and $ \mathbb{P}^{n} (k) = \mathrm{Proj} \ k[X_0 , \dots , X_n ]$ irreducibles?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-space, projective-schemes

Are $ \mathbb{A} (k ) = k^n $ and $ \mathbb{P}^{n} (k)  = \mathrm{Proj} \ k[X_0 , \dots , X_n ]$ irreducibles when $ k $ is a domain ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Not in general, consider $\mathbb{A}^1(\mathbb{F}_3)=\mathbb{F}_3$. It is the union $V(x) \cup V((x-1)(x-2))$

Comment: Thank you. :-) What about $ \mathbb{P}^n (k) $ ? What happens when $ k = \mathbb{C} $ ?

Comment: When $k=\mathbb{C}$ or any infinite field those spaces are irreducible for $n \geq 1$  There's a nice discussion [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/113918/proof-mathbban-is-irreducible-without-nullstellensatz)

Comment: Thank you very much  rVitale.  :-)

Comment: No problem glad it helped!